# Why is it bad to overextend the back when doing a deadlift?

Tags: deadlifts

It seems natural to me to overextend the back, as hips through would naturally lead to that on less than maximal lifts. Why are these exactly a bad thing?

Answer (score 3):

Some powerlifters do this to avoid red lights in competitions. They want the judges to see they pulled their shoulders behind their hips. But leaning back loads your spinal discs unevenly. It squeezes the back of your discs which can lead to injuries. You're not lifting the weight with your back on the deadlift.

Just keep your lower back neutral so you have the normal curve while standing up. If you can't figure it out, get someone that knows how to check your form to help you at the gym or (if alone) check in a mirror. I'd also advise filming a set or two from the side so you can check it while resting between sets, it helps a lot - just don't be obnoxious if you're in a public gym!

Comment: I agree, though many if not most people lack the proprioceptive capacity to even know when their lower back (ie. strictly speaking their pelvic bone relative to the longitudinal axis of the upper body) is in neutral position. Therefore, I suggest a mirror or a second person (plus the knowledge to judge it) for correction until one has a feeling for what neutral even means.